# Is it possible to change a generic variable into a specific one, or initialize a variable of a specific type with the value of a generic variable?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template <typename First>

class VerifyIfTrue{

    protected:
        First AG;
        int tries = 0;
        int vaalue;
        int RT;
        string whatis;
        string lie1;
        string lie2;

        VerifyIfTrue(string twhatis, string tlie1, string tlie2) : whatis(twhatis), lie1(tlie1), lie2(tlie2)
{input();}

        void input(){
            if(tries == 0){
            cout << "Tell me your " << whatis << "\n";}else{
            cout << "Come on, what's your " << whatis << "\n";}
            cin >> AG;

            if(typeid(AG).name() != typeid(int).name())
            {
                int x = 0;
                AG = x;
                cout << "Wrong type" << endl;
                ++tries;
                input();
            }else{
                int a = AG;
                positivetest(a);
            }
void positivetest(int RT){
            if(RT <=0)
            {
                cout << lie1 << "\n";
                if(tries == 0)
                {
                    ++tries;
                    cout << lie2 << "\n";

            }
            int y = 0;
            AG = y;
            ++tries;
            input();
            }else{
            vaalue = AG;
            }
        }
            }
...
```

I get the following error:

cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::basic_string' to 'int' in initialization|

Is there a way around this? I want to either be able to change AG into an int, so it can be passed into int parameters or tested if it's an int; or be able to assign its' value to an int

Comment: _"... generic variable. .."_ Generics are a Java thing. `First AG;` has a concrete type `First` which is set when you create an instance of `VerifyIfTrue<T>`.  Please post a [mcve] where an object of type `VerifyIfTrue` is instantiated.

Comment: I'm very new, didn't know the technical term

Comment: _"I'm very new..."_ writing template classes is kind of intermediate to advanced.  Can you solve your problem without writing a template class?

Comment: Upfront, there are missing braces. Please copy and format the code properly. You may start with an easier target than templates. If it must be templates, maybe a specialization for `int` works?

Comment: The problem i was looking to solve is how to make the program not crash if the user's input isn't the expected data type, IE, AG is expected to be an int, but cin >> AG can have a letter inputted instead and if it does there's a crash, what i want instead is for the program to remove the value of AG if that happens, and try again for the user to actually input an int, template classes were the first thing i ran into that might have solved that issue

Comment: Read user input as text (`std::string`), validate the input, if ok - convert to the type you want; if not ok - output a message.  Write some small helper functions eg `valid_read_int`; `valid_read_yn` etc

Comment: Then templates aren't the way to go, read into a string and do input validation.

Comment: Didn't even get taught input validation existed, thanks for the big help

Answer (score 0):

You might use `if constexpr` (c++17) with `std::is_same`:

```
if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<int, First>) {
    int x = 0;
    AG = x;
    cout << "Wrong type" << endl;
    ++tries;
    input();
} else {
    int a = AG;
    positivetest(a);
}
```